# Why isn't zsh performing brace expansion?

Tags: shell, zsh, brace-expansion

My default shell is zsh (`/bin/zsh`). When I first open a terminal session, brace expansion for characters does not work, while numeric expansion works fine. Running `zsh` to open a new shell fixes the problem:

```
$ zsh --version
zsh 5.0.8 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0)
$ echo {0..9}
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
$ echo {a..z}
{a..z} 
$ zsh
$ echo {a..z}
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
$ zsh --version
zsh 5.0.8 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0)
```

This occurs in both Terminal and iTerm, and is not due to any settings in `.zshrc` (it is unchanged in the absence of that file). The zsh version is the same in both cases, and is greater than 5.0.7, so this is not explained by [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394728/zsh-brace-expansion-seq-for-character-lists-how). I presume it's somehow related to the difference between a login/non-login shell, but I have no idea why it would do this.

Why isn't zsh performing brace expansion here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(zsh brace expansion | seq) for character lists - how?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394728/zsh-brace-expansion-seq-for-character-lists-how)

Comment: Have you installed a new version of `zsh`? My `/bin/zsh` is 5.0.5 and does not expand `{a..z}`. My `/usr/local/bin/zsh` is 5.0.7 and does.

Comment: To expand on chepner's comment. Try `which zsh` to see which zsh is being executed. Then you can check the version on both with `--version` to compare... possibly a homebrew version?

Comment: The doc of zsh v5.0.6 is the first to mention the brace expansion for characters, even though nothing is mentioned in the release notes.

Comment: My zsh version is greater than 5.0.7 (both before and after the second zsh call), so this is not a duplicate of [(zsh brace expansion | seq) for character lists - how?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394728/zsh-brace-expansion-seq-for-character-lists-how). Edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: @KevinBurdett calling `which zsh` inside the first session will not help. It is already established, that the first session starts the desired version of `zsh`. Instead compare the output of `echo $ZSH_VERSION` to see, whether it are indeed different versions. It is possible that either `PATH` did not include the desired directory when starting the first `zsh` (and it is only then updated by `zsh` itself) or *iTerm* and *Terminal* just call it with an absolute path (possibly from user settings?). If it is an absolute path `echo $0` should show it.