Pass variable from Automator into Shell Script to make a parent directory
I am trying to automate files with renaming and sorting on a per project basis. I was able to get what I wanted essentially, but want to take it a step further. In Automator, I ask for text then set value of Variable and call it "MovieTitle". Then The next action renames finder items replacing "XXXX" with variable "MovieTitle"
first part of automator actions
Then I have Run Shell Script that makes 4 folders, and then sorts the files into those folders:
for f in "$@"
do
    mkdir -p "/Users/kgstudio/Documents/• Designworks •/• VOD Automation •/Kaleidoscope/3. VOD/Amazon"
    mkdir -p "/Users/kgstudio/Documents/• Designworks •/• VOD Automation •/Kaleidoscope/3. VOD/iTunes"
    mkdir -p "/Users/kgstudio/Documents/• Designworks •/• VOD Automation •/Kaleidoscope/3. VOD/Microsoft"
    mkdir -p "/Users/kgstudio/Documents/• Designworks •/• VOD Automation •/Kaleidoscope/3. VOD/Google Play"

    if [[ $f == *"Amazon"* ]]
    then
        mv $f "/Users/kgstudio/Documents/• Designworks •/• VOD Automation •/Kaleidoscope/3. VOD/Amazon"
    fi
    
    if [[ $f == *"Google"* ]]
    then
        mv $f "/Users/kgstudio/Documents/• Designworks •/• VOD Automation •/Kaleidoscope/3. VOD/Google Play"
    fi
        
    if [[ $f == *"Microsoft"* ]]
    then
        mv $f "/Users/kgstudio/Documents/• Designworks •/• VOD Automation •/Kaleidoscope/3. VOD/Microsoft"
    fi

    if [[ $f == *"iTunes"* ]] || [[ $f == *"_#"* ]]
    then
        mv $f "/Users/kgstudio/Documents/• Designworks •/• VOD Automation •/Kaleidoscope/3. VOD/iTunes"
    fi
    
done

This actually works and does what I want even though I am sure the code could be refined/ more efficient. My main goal would be to make a parent directory that is the "MovieTitle" variable and have those 4 folders be subfolders of that parent. And also still have the files sort into those specific folders.
I tried a few different things that I read online and even with Chat GPT and nothing seemed to work. For testing, I just added a new line at the start of the script mkdir -p "$MovieTitle". I tried different variations of this, but a new folder was never added. Just the 4 with absolute paths.
Any help would be appreciated.

It's really not clear what you are asking. mkdir -p "$MovieTitle"/{foo,bar,baz} will create directories ick/foo, ick/bar, and ick/baz if $MovieTitle is ick; but do you have control over which directory they will be created in? (The brace expansion syntax assumes Bash; I guess something similar is available in Zsh, but not in plain sh.) Perhaps see also What exactly is current working directory?

Sorry, not familiar with Automator; but this might be relevant: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/278570/automator-use-current-directory-location

I guess you will find that the "$MovieTitle" directory was added in /Users/you

This would probably be very easy if you removed Automator from the equation. But if that's not an option, perhaps you can explain what file names are being passed in and how they relate to the expected result? For example, if I run this on /Users/me/Downloads/0001.mov and /Users/me/Downloads/0002.mov, could we just create the new directory in the common parent directory (in this case /Users/me/Downloads)? Or perhaps always the immediate parent directory of the first file? (Same result, in this case.)

(Tangentially https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35465560/why-isnt-zsh-performing-brace-expansion suggests that recent Zsh should support brace expansion as well.)

You could move the mkdir statements to in front of the loop. But this is less for efficiency (the repeated mkdir don't cost that much, unless your script is called very frequently).

Thanks for the comments and sorry if I wasn't clear. This is my first time trying to use automator and shell scripts. Just trying to piece together stuff. Here are 2 examples of file names:
XXXX_Microsoft_1800x1800.jpg
XXXX_Amazon_1920x1080.jpg
The "XXXX" is the variable I was to replace and that works using automator. I would like that same variable to carry over to the shell script to make a parent directory with that variable name, then make the subfolders inside of there.
I did check my home directory and searched computer for folders with variable, but found nothing.

Also I tried to make it more simple using the brace 'mkdir -p "/Path/{Amazon, iTunes, Microsoft, Google Play}"' But that makes a folder with that as a name, as well as 4 document files with the correct names, but not actual folders. I had run into similar problems before and why I kept each directory on its own line.

Doing some more experiments, I found out that if I use "$1" that does sort of work. Im guessing it means the first variable. If I use this shell script after Get selected Finder Items it mixes the variable with file and pathname. So now the issue is using that variable again to move the files into those newly created directories.

There probably is a more elegant answer to the original question, but I found a workaround, and am going to use it. This is a different example with a different folder structure, but exact same idea of making a project folder with a set number of sub folders and having the files sort into the correct folders.

I start with the shell script to make the directories with absolute paths and move the files into their correct folders.
Then ask for text and set as variable.
Then use built in automator actions to rename everything with that variable.

As with anything, I am sure there are a ton of ways to do the same thing, and it can all be done in a shell script I am sure but could not figure it out.
Automator
