# How to loop through a range of characters in a bash script using ASCII values?

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to write a bash script which will read two letter variables (startletter/stopletter) and after that I need to print from the start letter to the stop letter with a for or something else. How can I do that?

I tried to do

```
#! /bin/bash 

echo "give start letter" 
read start 
echo "give stop letter" read stop
```

But none of the for constructs work

```
#for value in {a..z} 
#for value in {$start..$stop} 
#for (( i=$start; i<=$stop; i++)) do echo "Letter: $c" done
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the input and output? Do you mean `$startletter=c` `$stopletter=f` `output=cdef` ? (assuming English alphabet order)

Comment: `eval echo {$start..$stop}` is the easiest. But it is worth checking if there are any security implications of using `eval` here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looping through alphabets in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7300070/608639).

Answer (score 2):

This question is very well explained in [BashFAQ/071 How do I convert an ASCII character to its decimal (or hexadecimal) value and back?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/071)

```
# POSIX
# chr() - converts decimal value to its ASCII character representation
# ord() - converts ASCII character to its decimal value

chr () {
  local val
  [ "$1" -lt 256 ] || return 1
  printf -v val %o "$1"; printf "\\$val "
  # That one requires bash 3.1 or above.
}

ord() {
  # POSIX
  LC_CTYPE=C printf %d "'$1"
}
```

Re-using them for your requirement, a proper script would be written as

```
read -p "Input two variables: " startLetter stopLetter
[[ -z "$startLetter" || -z "$stopLetter" ]] && { printf 'one of the inputs is empty\n' >&2 ; }

asciiStart=$(ord "$startLetter") 
asciiStop=$(ord "$stopLetter") 

for ((i=asciiStart; i<=asciiStop; i++)); do
    chr "$i"
done
```

Would print the letters as expected.

---

Adding it to community-wiki since this is also a cross-site duplicate from [Unix.SE - Bash script to get ASCII values for alphabet](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92447/bash-script-to-get-ascii-values-for-alphabet)

Comment: Wow! I never knew about that printf leading single or double quote trick! I just looked through a bunch of answers to related questions and you're the only one who seems to know about it!

Answer (score 2):

In case you feel adventurous and want to use `zsh` instead of `bash`, you can use the following:

- For zsh versions below [5.0.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394728/zsh-brace-expansion-seq-for-character-lists-how) you can use the `BRACE_CCL` option:

> **(snip man zshall)** If  a  brace expression matches none of the above forms, it is left
>   unchanged, unless the option `BRACE_CCL` (an abbreviation for 'brace character class') is set.  In that case, it is expanded to a list of the individual characters between the braces sorted into the order of the characters in the ASCII character set (multibyte characters are not currently handled).  The syntax is similar to a `[...]` expression in filename generation: `-`  is  treated specially to denote a range of characters, but `^` or `!` as the first character is treated normally.  For example, `{abcdef0-9}`
>   expands to 16 words `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

setopt brace_ccl
echo "give start letter" 
read cstart 
echo "give stop letter"
read cstop

for char in {${cstart}-${cstop}}; do echo $char; done
```

- For zsh versions from [5.0.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394728/zsh-brace-expansion-seq-for-character-lists-how) onwards you can use the default brace expansion :

> An expression of the form `{c1..c2}`, where `c1` and `c2` are single characters (which may be multibyte characters), is expanded to every character in the range from `c1` to `c2` in whatever character sequence is used internally. For characters with code points below 128 this is US ASCII (this is the only case most users will need). If any intervening character is not printable, appropriate quotation is used to render it printable. If the character sequence is reversed, the output is in reverse order, e.g. `{d..a}` is substituted as `d c b a`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

echo "give start letter" 
read cstart 
echo "give stop letter"
read cstop

for char in {${cstart}..${cend}; do echo $char; done
```

More information on `zsh` can be found [here](http://zsh.sourceforge.net) and the [quick reference](http://www.bash2zsh.com/zsh_refcard/refcard.pdf)