# Zsh parameter expansion

Tags: bash, zsh

How do I get the following z shell script to function the same way that it would in bash?

```
for x in {f..k}
    do echo ${x}
done
```

In bash I get f j k printed out but in zsh, I get {f..k} printed literally.

EDIT

What I'm actually trying to do (should have mentioned this initially) is:

```
FIRSTLETTER=a
LASTLETTER=b
for x in {$FIRSTLETTER..$LASTLETTER}
do 
    echo "/dev/sd${x}1"
done
```

Comment: `bash` is the shell that expands `{$FIRSTLETTER..$LASTLETTER}` to `{a..b}`; `zsh` should correctly expand it to `a b`.

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394728/zsh-brace-expansion-seq-for-character-lists-how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `bash`, brace expansion happens before parameter expansion. The result is that `{$FIRSTLETTER..$LASTLETTER}` isn't subject to brace expansion, because it's not a valid sequence expression:

> A sequence expression takes the form {x..y[..incr]}, where x and y  are
>          either  integers or single characters

Only then does the literal string undergo parameter expansion, resulting in the single word `{a..b}`.

In `zsh`, brace expansion occurs *after* several other types of expansion, include parameter expansion, have occurred. Thus, `{$FIRST_LETTER..$LAST_LETTER}` expands to `{a..b}`, which then undergoes brace expansion to produce `a b`.

The end result is that what you are doing should work in `zsh`, but not in `bash`. Further, short of using `eval`, there is no way to do what you want in `bash`.

```
for x in $(eval "echo {$FIRSTLETTER..$LASTLETTER}")
```

Keep in mind that this is fragile, and requires you to be *very* sure that the two parameters can only expand to single letters each.

Comment: This absolutely worked out. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

It works:

```
for x ({f..k}); echo ${x}
```

Comment: Still get {f..k} as the output.

Comment: perhaps consider using an updated version of zsh? Mine is zsh 5.3.1

Comment: It appears that 5.0.2 is the latest for RHEL7

Answer (score 0):

No zsh handy, just trying a workaround. Will it do this?

```
for o in $(seq 102 107)
do x=$(printf %x $o)
   printf "\x$x"
done
```